# Python: Using Classes to re-ask a prompt if answer is incorrect

Tags: python-2.7, class

The code below creates a hero named Luke. Luke has to choose if he wants to eat apples or ham from the table of food he found.

If the user doesn't pick "apple" or "ham", how can I make it so that the user is re-asked the question to choose "apple" or "ham"?

I want to learn how to do this within a class. I feel as though I need to do something below my print statement in else, but `self.food()` leads to an error saying str is not callable.

```
    class Hero():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.health = 100   
        self.food = raw_input("You encounter a table full of apples and ham. Which do you eat first? ") 

    def eat(self):  
        x = True
        while x == True:
            if (self.food == 'apple'):
                self.health -= 100
                print "%s has %d health points" % (self.name, self.health)
                x = False
            elif (self.food == 'ham'):
                self.health += 20
                print self.health
                print "%s has %d health points" % (self.name, self.health)
                x = False
            else:
                print "Incorrect. Please try again"
                break

char_1 = Hero("Luke")
char_1.eat()
```

Edit:

Changes after Alex's help.

```
class Hero():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.health = 100

    def eat(self):
        while self.health > 0:
            food = raw_input("You encounter a table full of apples and ham. Which do you eat first? ")
            if (food == 'apple'):
                self.health -= 10
                print "%s has %d health points" % (self.name, self.health)
            elif (food == 'ham'):
                self.health += 20
                print self.health
                print "%s has %d health points" % (self.name, self.health)
            else:
                print "Incorrect. Please try again"


char_1 = Hero("Luke")
char_1.eat()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the while loop which ensures that a sensible food is chosen in the initialiser, not the `eat` method. The `raw_input` should be inside that loop so that the user can enter a food repeatedly until they get it right. The logic about health can remain in the `eat` method. Also you don't want to `break` when they get it wrong, you want the loop to keep going, so remove that. However you can `break` when they get it right instead of setting `x = False`, and then the loop can just be written as `while True: ...` and you can get rid of the `x` entirely.

By the way, if you were still using the `x`, that's a terrible choice of variable name. Proper naming is essential, get into the right habit now.

Also `while x == True:` is redundant, you can just write `while x:`.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I didn't really understand how the while loop would work in the initializer method, so I instead moved my raw_input statement under the while condition in the eat method and that worked. Thanks for the "x" variable name pointer. I'm just practicing tonight and didn't really think about it. But I will get in the habit!